# Passing templated Unions of plain structs across ABIs safely

Tags: c++, struct, unions, abi, dynamic-loading

I have defined the following union template, for a 2D vector, with multiple attribute names:

```
template<T> union vec2
{
    struct {
        T x;
        T y;
    };
    struct {
        T u;
        T v;
    };
    struct {
        T i;
        T j;
    };
    struct {
        T width;
        T height;
    };
    template<ST> vec2(vec2<ST> other) : x(other.x), y(other.y);
    vec2() : x(0), y(0);
    vec2(T v1, T v2) : x(v1), y(v2);
}
```

While I believe this is safe to pass between ABIs with out causing errors, because:

All members are the same type, hence struts will be packed without any extra padding.

Constructor functions are inline, and simply set the attributes of the first struct.

So the union should count as POD

Intended usage,

template is in a header include by both main application, and external library (possibly compiled with different compiler)

say I have the following type of function pointer, from the external libary

```
typedef void* (__fastcall *createWindow)(vec2<uint16_t>, char* title);
```

My understanding is that calling

```
void* window = createWindow(vec2<uint16_t>(320,240), "Test Window");
```

would be completely safe, as vec2 is just two 16bit integers pack into a 32bit integer containing the values (320, 240), and as along as the library are compiled for the same platform i.e. 32bit windows, they will store this data exactly the same (as the structs shouldn't have padding), thus my library from which I dynamically loaded createWindow from can access the values, using any of the attribute pairs, i.e. width = 320, height = 240.

Is my reasoning correct, If not is there a way to make this safely work, note I need templates so conversion from say vec2 to vec2 can be made.